# The value returned in this program is. . . .Queer to say the least

Tags: c

So, I was experimenting with assembly and pointers, so I decided to do a little extra, I made a new integer , d and assigned the function exchange to it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int exchange(int *xp, int *yp, int *zp){
   int x = *xp; 
   int y = *yp; 
   int z = *zp;

   *xp = z;
   *yp = x; 
   *zp = y;  
}


int main(){
   int a = 3;
   int b = 12;
   int c = 24;
   exchange(&a, &b, &c);
   printf("int a = %d, int b = %d, int c = %d : ", a, b, c);
   int d = exchange(&a, &b, &c);
   printf("\n int d = %d", d);
   return 0;

}
```

So, when I do the exchange function , it works as intended, switching the values in the registers. Except. . . .d returned a weird number: 6356768.

I'm not sure why d returns that value, but I would be much obliged if somebody would explain how it happened.

Comment: Your compiler doesn't warn you about a function not returning a value like it should?

Comment: It does not, no.

Comment: Undefined behaviour when you try to use the return value from a function that doesn't return a value.

Comment: If your compiler does not complain, you are either not using enough warning options or you need to get a better compiler.  If you're using Turbo C, get a better compiler — one from the second decade of the current millennium, not the penultimate decade of the last millennium.  If you use GCC, try `gcc -std=c11 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes`.  They're about my base-level of warnings; I don't usually run code that doesn't compile with those (at least, not when it is my code; other people's code is sometimes a different matter).

Comment: You really should turn on warnings, then (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang), and then pay attention to them.

Comment: How do I turn them on in JGRASP?

Comment: What's JGRASP?  Oh, it's [JGRASP](https://www.jgrasp.org/).  The manual probably tells you.  The help system may tell you.

Comment: http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jdalbey/101/Resources/GettingStarted/jGRASPSetup.html shows how to setup warnings.

Comment: See [How can I set compiler flags](https://www.jgrasp.org/faq.html#compflags) in the jGRASP FAQ.

Comment: still amazing that this is not a fatal error by default

Comment: @pm100: It's not because of the legacy of pre-standard C, where there wasn't a `void` return type necessarily (and a lot of code pre-dated the late addition of the `void` return type), so functions were written with no explicit return type (default ot `int`) and with just `return;` in the function because there was no returned value, and as long as you didn't try to capture or test the value that wasn't returned, it was OK.

Comment: @pm100:  See C11 [§6.9.1 Function definitions ¶12](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p12): _If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined._  [§6.8.6.4 The `return` statement ¶1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.6.4p1) says: _A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is `void`. A `return` statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is `void`._ Earlier versions of standard C were more lax, I believe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler iamgine how much easier life would be for all if modern c compilers defaulted to -wall -werror. Non beginners would prove that they were not beginners by discovering the -Wdontnag option. Advanced users would also take the dontnag option back off (cos we all like squeaky clean code)

Comment: Read the warnings and this question would never been asked

Comment: @P__J__ I guess you can say I've been warned.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have not returned anything from `exchange` whose return type is `int`. Hence what you see is garbage for the value of `d`. Try returning a status flag like `1` for success.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int exchange(int *xp, int *yp, int *zp) {
    int x = *xp; 
    int y = *yp; 
    int z = *zp;

    *xp = z;
    *yp = x; 
    *zp = y;  
    return 1;
}


int main(){
    int a = 3;
    int b = 12;
    int c = 24;
    exchange(&a, &b, &c);
    printf("int a = %d, int b = %d, int c = %d : ", a, b, c);
    int d = exchange(&a, &b, &c);
    printf("\n int d = %d\n", d);
    return 0;

}
```

You should see something like,

```
int a = 24, int b = 3, int c = 12 :
 int d = 1
```

Let me know if this helps !!

Comment: The trouble with returning a flag like `1` for success is that your calling code should check for success, but it won't ever get a failure (there's only the `return 1;` in the function), so in fact it would be better if the function returned nothing, which is spelled `void`: `void exchange(…)` — and no `return` or just `return;` in the function body (and there should be no attempt to capture or print the non-existent value that wasn't returned, of course).

Comment: And, in general, C uses 0 to indicate success anyway, IIRC.

Comment: @DaveNewton: A lot of C code uses 0 for success, especially if it originated in the Unix world.  Some code does not, though — a notable example is the OpenSSL library.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in this case the statement `int d = exchange(&a, &b, &c);` would cause an error. He uses a return `int` type function and even stores it in some value during function call. I just assumed that it has some meaning, flag or otherwise (subject to specific interpretation).

Comment: It helped, in the end I just made it a void.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell where is wrong in your program, so I put your code on my IDE, and surprisingly it even can't build. And the warning shows : `Control reaches end of non-void function in Line 12` (the end `}` of the exchange function). so i tried to fix this problem by add a sentence : return z; . And it works!

I think it's because your function exchange is an int value returned function, unlike the void kind, it has to have a return value. so add one to it. it will run very well

Comment: Note that `return x, y, z;` is a peculiar use of the comma operator, equivalent to writing just `return z;` (except that a fussy compiler won't warn you about unused expressions with no side-effects, whereas the version with the comma operator will generate such a warnings).  Note also my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750299/the-value-returned-in-this-program-is-queer-to-say-the-least#comment92424991_52750346) to another answer here.

Answer (score 1):

**Not a proper answer, just an interesting observation:**

I added some `printf`s in your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int exchange(int *xp, int *yp, int *zp){
   int x = *xp; 
   int y = *yp; 
   int z = *zp;
   printf("xp = %p, yp = %p, zp = %p\n", xp, yp, zp);

   *xp = z;
   *yp = x; 
   *zp = y; 
}


int main(){
   int a = 3;
   int b = 12;
   int c = 24;
   printf("&a = %p, &b = %p, &c = %p\n", &a, &b, &c);
   exchange(&a, &b, &c);
   int d = exchange(&a, &b, &c);
   printf("int d = %x\n", d);
   return 0;
}
```

And ran it on my computer (gcc 7.3.0 on Ubuntu 18.04), and got this output:

```
&a = 0x7ffca0126788, &b = 0x7ffca012678c, &c = 0x7ffca0126790
xp = 0x7ffca0126788, yp = 0x7ffca012678c, zp = 0x7ffca0126790
xp = 0x7ffca0126788, yp = 0x7ffca012678c, zp = 0x7ffca0126790
int d = a0126790
```

It appears that lower 32 bits of the parameter `zp` is being returned from `exchange`. But If I move the call to `printf` to the end of `exchange`, it always returns 62, which is the value returned from printf itself.

My guess is, when you don't return a value from a function, probably the register used to hold the value to be returned retains the value returned by the subsequent function call. If no more function is called, then *somehow* it gets the value of a parameter, which I can't explain or guess.

But all these things are specific to the gcc on my computer (maybe yours too). Actually this is undefined behavior and you never know what would happen (quoting one of my professors: "The universe might get destroyed, who knows?").

When I ran the same code [on ideone](https://www.ideone.com/BRfBsu) (which is gcc 6.3), I found the returned value to be 0.

Comment: Nothing interesting in it. It was lower part of the address accidently in the register used for the address calculations.

Comment: `eax` is the register used for return value (most likely)

Comment: "The universe might get destroyed, who  knows?" I love that. It's like one day this robot gave this woman her coffee and BOOM. Fallout 4.